# Why an XML Create Schema Error in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2013, xsd

A little off course from the norm, but a coworker is having issues generating an xsd from a simple xml model and I really don't know much about why they would be getting an error. I loaded the same xml document and didn't get the error. We are both using VS2013.

Here's the XML

```
<CustomerCreditCheckResponse>
    <Result>0</Result>
    <CreditStatus>0</CreditStatus> 
    <AvailableCredit>50000.00</AvailableCredit>
    <StatedCreditLimit>100000.00</StatedCreditLimit>
    <HoldCreditLimit>100000.00</HoldCreditLimit>
    <AccountStatus>0</AccountStatus>
</CustomerCreditCheckResponse>
```

The error received is

> 'Create Schema Error' --> startIndex cannot be larger than length of
>   string. Parameter name: startIndex

Comment: That error seems to come from a `string.Format()` method call. Perhaps your coworker is using a plugin of some sort that tries to report something, but has an error? Try running Visual Studio in safe mode to find out whether the issue persists. If it goes away, disable any add-ins, plugins, extensions and re-enable one by one until you have found the culprit.

Comment: As an alternative, with such trivial XML you can create the necessary XSD in minutes without resorting to (usually quite wrong) auto-generation tools. Also, Visual Studio uses almost the same as `xsd.exe`, you can try on your coworker's machine [running it from the commandline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after generating the XML with the select * from MyView for XML AUTO, Elements query. This occurred after attempting to 'Create Schema' from VS 2013 when opening the XML file directly from the SQLQuery Results tab. Saving the document to another location with a short name 'TestXML' or whatever allowed the tool to create the appropriate schema without error.